Questions about when to prove for the special case of the empty set
So the lecture notes I am reading proved a theorem: A function $f \colon A \to B$, with $A \neq \emptyset$ is injective if and only if it has a left inverse, and it's surjective if and only if it has a right inverse. The proof of the first part did assume that the set $A$ had at least one element in order to construct the left inverse. The idea is that you select a fixed element of $A$ and send every element to its pre-image (which is unique) and every element that doesn't have a pre-image you send it to that fixed element. So clearly this proof is no longer valid if we remove the restriction that $A \neq \emptyset$, and in fact the theorem can be false if we don't have that restriction (consider a function goes from $\emptyset \to \{0, 1\}$ it is vacuously injective and yet a left inverse does not exist).
However, the second part of the theorem will technically still be true even if we don't require $A \neq \emptyset$. The proof of the second part (at least one direction of the iff) was something like this: given that $f$ is surjective, we want to construct $g \colon B \to A$, every element of $B$ has at least one pre-image under $f$, so construct the right inverse by choosing any pre-image and sending the element to the selected pre-image. This function will indeed be a righ inverse of $f$.
My questions are, is the second part of the proof valid even if $A = \emptyset$? I know that part of the theorem holds true even if the restriction on $A$ is removed, but I want to know if this specific proof is a valid way to show that. I believe it might still be valid, because we never assumed there was any element in $A$, all of our steps are of the form "for all x in B" which are vacuously true. I would also like to know, if it was you writing the proof, would you write a separate proof for the case where $A$ is empty even if the general case proof is also valid for that case? Just for the sake of improving clarity.

It's probably valid.  There is only one function, the empty function, from the emptyset to any set and it's pretty easy to know everything about it.  $f:\emptyset\to B$ is surjective if and only if $B=\emptyset$ (thats easy to prove) and for any function going the other way, $g:B\to \emptyset$, can only exist as a function at all if $B=\emptyset$.  Now the only function from $\emptyset\to \emptyset$ is vacuously an identity function.  So if $A=\emptyset$ the $f:A\to B$ is surjective if and only if $B$ is empty and therefore there is an empty identy function from $B\to A$.
